# Cyclic Error with MySQL and Java Connection

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to create a MySQL DB for my program to connect to. I have ensured that Maven's library was added properly.

I'd like my program to create the database reviews if it's not created and if it isn't created then do I need to make sure that it connects without running the program all over again.

My current code is as follows:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "pass";

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        int result = stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS reviews");
```

I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'reviews.reviews' doesn't exist
```

Now, if I change code to:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "pass";

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        int result = stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE reviews");
```

I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can't create database 'reviews'; database exists
```